# Get ID from template model form and display data from db django ajax django model forms

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a view which starts by displaying the latest ID and data related to that id from the database.

Please see the sample form here.
http://i63.tinypic.com/s2gyhc.jpg

I want to get that displayed ID, send it to my view, increment it and display the data corresponding to next ID.

I have already posted the ID to the view. Now how do i show the new data without refreshing?

Ajax code

```
$("#next").click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'/next/',
          data:{
                voucher_id:$('#id_voucher_id').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
          },
          success:function(){
                alert('yo!')
          }
    });
          return false;});
```

Views.py

```
def master_detail_next(request):

    author_form = TmpForm()

    ''' Decide what we want to show'''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        author = TmpForm(request.POST)
        voucher_id = str(int(request.POST['voucher_id']) + 1)

        ''' Define the three forms here'''
        author = TmpPlInvoice.objects.get(voucher_id=voucher_id)
        author_form = TmpForm(instance=author)

        return render_to_response('main.html',
                              {'form': author_form},
                             context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How can i do this in Django model forms/Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Found the right way. 
The form which needs to be updated should be in another template file.

```
    $("#previous").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
            url:'/next/',
            data:{
                voucher_id:$('#id_voucher_id').val(),
          csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            success:searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });
   });


        function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
          {
            $('#myForm').html(data);
       }
```